# Git messes up the branch name

Tags: git

Some times git creates the wrong branch name (see example below).

```
|ssc-7132b → origin/development ↑1 {3} ✓| → git push mine ssc-7132b:ssc-7132
Counting objects: 14, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (14/14), done.
Writing objects: 100% (14/14), 1.53 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 14 (delta 11), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (11/11), completed with 11 local objects.
remote: 
remote: Create a pull request for 'ssc-7137132' on GitHub by visiting:
remote:      https://github.rakops.com/melissa-dailey/shopstyle-collective/pull/new/ssc-7137132
remote: 
To github.rakops.com:melissa-dailey/shopstyle-collective.git
 * [new branch]        ssc-7132b -> ssc-7137132
```

Note that the remote branch is typed correctly:

```
ssc-7132b:ssc-7132
```

yet the remote branch created is:

```
ssc-7137132
```

This happens when creating a new local or remote branch. Doesn't happen every single time, its infrequent about twice a month.

Comment: That's very interesting. I don't think Git is doing something here. Maybe some kind of shell-expansion? Which shell are you using?

Comment: You didn't show us the command you ran, just the output

Comment: Looks like a `git push origin` to me....

Answer (score 0):

I would think the push command set the wrong name:

```
git push some-remote ssc-7132b:ssc-7137132
```

That would replicate what happened there if ssc-7132b exists locally.